# Write a method that performs performs arithmetic operations on two instances of the same class

Tags: python, oop, finance

Trying to use OOP to avoid having to explicitly state all parameters of similar financial instruments

This non OOP approach works. I explicitly feed the same attributes twice depending on the instance

```
def interpolate_G_Spread(Maturity_Lower,Maturity_Upper,Maturity):
    Weight= (Maturity-Maturity_Lower)/(Maturity_Upper-Maturity_Lower)
    return Weight
```

Trying to convert the above code to OOP

```
class Bond:
    def __init__(self,Price,Maturity,Yield):
        self.Price=Price
        self.Maturity=Maturity
        self.Yield=Yield
```

Kinda stuck here as I cannot have a second Maturity Parameter

```
    def Interpolate_G_Spread(self,Maturity):
        Weight=self.Maturity
```

Comment: I have very little financial domain knowledge, but why do you need a second `Maturity` parameter? It seems like you should have `Maturity_Upper` and `Maturity_Lower` parameters, along with `self`.

Comment: Hi Carcigenicate. I appreciate you taking the time. Maturity is a unique attribute of a Bond. What I'm trying to do here is to enter many bonds in a class and perform arithmetic operations on their distinct attributes (Maturity, Yield and Price).

Comment: In the first method I invoke three bonds. Bond 1 with Maturity_Lower. Bond 2 with Maturity. Bond 3 with Maturity_Upper.

Comment: Basically, in my mind the class should function as a data frame. and the method should allow me perform calculations on the Maturity column. My primary language is T-SQL hence this mental model. Your input will be very much appreciated.